# Running nohup many times in a script

Tags: bash, scripting, nohup

Related to an earlier question I asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676358/running-python-script-many-times-in-a-bash-file). So I have the following script:

```bsh
requests=(25 50 75 100)
factors=(3 6)
graphsizes=(25 50 75)

for request in "${requests[@]}" 
do
  for factor in "${factors[@]}"
  do
    for size in "${graphsizes[@]}"
    do
        echo "Now Running: n = ${request}, factor = ${factor}, size = ${size}" >> nohup.out
        nohup python3 -u main.py "$request" 50 "$factor" "$size" > ${request}_${factor}_${size}.log 
        echo "Done Running: n = ${request}, factor = ${factor}, size = ${size}" >> nohup.out
    done
  done
done
```

My intention: I want to run all the various permutation of arguments to `main.py` sequentially; i.e., print `Now Running...`, then call `nohup` and run the python script, when that is done print `Done running...`

Note that I cannot add a `&` at the end of the `nohup` line, since that would make the script proceed before `main.py` has finished.

However, by not using the `&`, I can no longer use the current shell process while this script is running. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You can use `nohup script_name &`...

Comment: @AndreWildberg I can't use the `&`, please see the question text...

Comment: I’d remove the nohup from within the script and instead call the whole script with nohup. That would execute and detach the script and run the permutations sequentially.

Comment: Why do you need nohup at all?
As a suggestion, you can put three commands in separate block or separate script and invoke it with arguments/exported environments.

Comment: @AndreWildberg `nohup` does not detach anything. All that nohup does is ignore the `SIGHUP` signal, do some very clumsy and obtuse redirections if the stdin/stdout/stderr are ttys (littering random directories with `nohup.out` files with mixed non-sync'ed output from multiple programs), and execute the command it was given as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course put the whole loop in background. Example:

```
for a in 1 2; do
   for b in 11 22; do
      for c in 111 222; do
          sleep 1; echo "$a $b $c"
      done
   done
done &
# notice the '&' at the end of the previous line
echo LOOP DONE
# put other commands here
wait
echo SCRIPT DONE # after 8 seconds
```

Notice that you do NOT want to use `nohup`, ever; just ignore the `SIGHUP` signal once with `trap '' HUP` and that "ignore" disposition will be inherited by all child processes.